# Read binary u32 using nom

Tags: rust, nom

I'm having a hard time finding any useful examples of how to use nom to parse a binary file, since it seems that the documentation is heavily biased towards `&str` input parsers.

I just want to make a function here that will read 4 bytes, turn it into a `u32` and return it as a result. Here is my function:

```
fn take_u32(input: &[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], u32> {
    map_res(
        take(4),
        |bytes| Ok(u32::from_be_bytes(bytes))
    )(input)
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u8; 4]: From<u8>` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:16:9
   |
16 |         take(4),
   |         ^^^^ the trait `From<u8>` is not implemented for `[u8; 4]`
   | 
  ::: C:\Users\cmbas\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\nom-7.1.0\src\bits\complete.rs:39:6
   |
39 |   O: From<u8> + AddAssign + Shl<usize, Output = O> + Shr<usize, Output = O>,
   |      -------- required by this bound in `nom::complete::take`
```

What is the canonical way to do what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`take()`](https://docs.rs/nom/7.1.0/nom/trait.InputTake.html#tymethod.take) return `Self` aka your input, In your case slice `&[u8]`.

[`map_res()`](https://docs.rs/nom/7.1.0/nom/combinator/fn.map_res.html) is used to map a `Result`, [`from_be_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_be_bytes) doesn't return a result, the doc also contains an example using `TryInto::try_into`.

To make your code compile you need to use [`map_opt()`](https://docs.rs/nom/7.1.0/nom/combinator/fn.map_opt.html) and use `try_into()` to transform the slice to array:

```rust
fn take_u32(input: &[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], u32> {
    map_opt(
        take(4),
        |bytes| int_bytes.try_into().map(u32::from_be_bytes)
    )(input)
}
```

That said nom already have such basic conbinator [`be_u32`](https://docs.rs/nom/7.1.0/nom/number/complete/fn.be_u32.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know of any good examples of nom being used to parse binary files? I find it helps me to have lots of reference to work from.

Comment: @ColinBasnett nom has a list of project in the readme but here a simple one I work on https://docs.rs/pktparse/0.7.0/pktparse/ that I think give some hint but it's clearly not perfect cause there is no precise error. I personally work on another conbinator parser cause I'm not happy with nom error and other problem but anyway this would give you a good base, easy to catch up.